# How to get element by Xpath in HtmlUnit

Tags: java, xpath, htmlunit

I am trying to search Amazon. I want to choose category, for ex.  Books, type some search criteria, for ex. java and to click Go button. My problem is clicking the Go button. I've got exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
>   0, Size: 0    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:571)   at
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:349)   at
>   Bot.clickSubmitButton(Bot.java:77)    at Bot.main(Bot.java:111)

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * @author ivan.bisevac
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImageInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlOption;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSelect;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;

public class Bot {
    private HtmlPage currentPage;

    public HtmlPage getCurrentPage() {
        return currentPage;
    }

    public Bot() {

    }

    /**
     * Bot constructor
     * 
     * @param pageAddress
     *            Address to go.
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws MalformedURLException
     * @throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException
     */
    public Bot(String pageAddress) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException,
            MalformedURLException, IOException {
        this();
        this.goToAddress(pageAddress);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param pageAddress
     * @throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException
     * @throws MalformedURLException
     *             If pageAddress isn't formatted good (for example, it is just
     *             www.google.com without http://) then this exception is thrown
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void goToAddress(String pageAddress)
            throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException,
            IOException {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        currentPage = webClient.getPage(pageAddress);
    }

    /**
     * Fills text into input field
     * 
     * @param inputId
     *            <input> tag id
     * @param textValue
     *            Text to fill into input field
     */
    public void setInputValue(String inputId, String textValue) {
        HtmlInput input = (HtmlInput) currentPage.getElementById(inputId);
        input.setValueAttribute(textValue);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param buttonId
     *            Button id
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void clickImageButton(String xpathExpr) throws IOException {
        HtmlImageInput button = (HtmlImageInput) currentPage
                .getFirstByXPath(xpathExpr);
        currentPage = (HtmlPage) button.click();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param radioButtonId
     * @param radioButtonOption
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public void selectRadioButton(String radioButtonId, String radioButtonOption)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final HtmlInput radio = (HtmlInput) currentPage
                .getElementById(radioButtonId);
        radio.click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param dropListId
     * @param dropListOption
     */
    public void selectDropList(String dropListId, String dropListOption) {
        HtmlSelect select = (HtmlSelect) currentPage.getElementById(dropListId);
        HtmlOption option = select.getOptionByValue(dropListOption);
        select.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Bot bot = new Bot("http://www.amazon.com");
        bot.selectDropList("searchDropdownBox", "search-alias=stripbooks");
        bot.setInputValue("twotabsearchtextbox", "java");
        bot.clickImageButton("//div[@id='navGoButton']/input");
        bot.getCurrentPage().getTitleText();
    }
}
```

Obvoiusly there is some problem in method clickSumbitButton, in selecting input element inside div. It gives empty array. Would someone help me to solve this problem?

Edit: After refactoring method clickImageButton, I have error on line:
    currentPage = (HtmlPage) button.click();
Here is stack trace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   Bot.clickImageButton(Bot.java:81)     at Bot.main(Bot.java:114)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
bot.clickSubmitButton("//div[@id='navGoButton']/input");
```

I would also recommend you to take a look at: [getFirstByXPath](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getFirstByXPath%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I edited my question. Can you suggest me some way to select this image input?

Comment: If button.click() fires a NullPointerException then button is obviously null. That means you are not getting it properly. However as of the code I'm seeing at amazon, the solution I've provided should work. Try to debug it with System.out.println(currentPage.asXml()); because you might be missing something else (probably you are not in the webpage you think you are)

Comment: I don't know how, but now I don't have exception. Thanks.